# Use of single quotes in select query while aggregating data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the difference between

1. select avg('orders') and
2. select avg(orders) in MySQL?

Also, are both correct in syntax?

If yes, when do you use each of them?

Comment: in first query 'orders' is string

Comment: Without the quotes is used the most. Then there also is the one where they use backticks.

Comment: `average` can be count on numeric values only, not for strings.

Answer (score 2):

The AVG() function returns the average value of a `numeric column`.

```
 avg('orders')  always return 0 because avg of string ('orders') is zero
```

Or

```
Avg(orders) return average of column orders
```

correct syntax

```
Avg(`orders`) or Avg(orders) are correct syntax
```

Comment: then why use avg('orders') because if you use avg , you would not want to return zero right?

Comment: yes because AVG() function returns the average value of a **numeric column** not string type @RaviHariani